# Find the last record that meet certain conditions in a group and create a new column based on the type of records in python

Tags: python, select, filter

I'm trying to create an new column 'newtype' based the following rules:

1. find the last record within an 'id' which has 'skill' = 'bill'
2. then create new column: the 'type' of the skill find in the above step is the newtype of the whole group.

For example, the input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2,2,3,3,3,4],
"skill": ['cc', 'bill', 'cc', 'cc','bill','a','bill','bill','bill'],
 "type": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b','a','a','a','b','a']})
df
```

The results I want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"id": [1, 1, 1, 2,2,3,3,3,4],
 "skill": ['cc', 'bill', 'cc', 'cc','bill','a','bill','bill','bill'],
 "type": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b','a','a','a','b','a'],
 "newtype": ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a','a','b','b','b','a']})
df
```

Can anyone show me how to achieve the above results? Thank you!!!

Comment: What have you already tried to solve this issue? Please provide the code you want feedback on so we can [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to solve the problem, and that's why I ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 'group' you're referring to consists of rows with the same 'id' value, this is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2,2,3,3,3,4],
"skill": ['cc', 'bill', 'cc', 'cc','bill','a','bill','bill','bill'],
 "type": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b','a','a','a','b','a']})

def get_type(row):
    df_temp = df[df['id'] == row['id'] ]
    return df_temp[df_temp['skill'].str.contains('bill')].iloc[-1]['type']
 
df['newtype'] = df.apply(lambda row:get_type(row), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
|    |   id | skill   | type   | newtype   |
|---:|-----:|:--------|:-------|:----------|
|  0 |    1 | cc      | a      | a         |
|  1 |    1 | bill    | a      | a         |
|  2 |    1 | cc      | b      | a         |
|  3 |    2 | cc      | b      | a         |
|  4 |    2 | bill    | a      | a         |
|  5 |    3 | a       | a      | b         |
|  6 |    3 | bill    | a      | b         |
|  7 |    3 | bill    | b      | b         |
|  8 |    4 | bill    | a      | a         |
```

Through df.apply every row is passed through a function that filters the df for rows with the same id (belonging to the same group), then looks up the 'type' value of the last match of a 'bill' skill in that group and returns that value to populate 'newtype'.

Comment: This is what I want! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote answers to your question and please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer you found most useful.